# Make compiler aware a Java function never returns

Tags: scala, exception

My Scala code (implementing a Jackson deserializer) calls a Java function which always throws (`DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken`). If this would be a Scala function, its return type would be `Nothing` and the compiler would be aware the code after it is unreachable. Currently I use `???` after the function call to mark this, I could also use any `throw` instead, but perhaps there is some better way, some annotation or something?

```
  class XDeserializer extends StdDeserializer[X](classOf[X]) {
    def deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext) = {
      if (p.getCurrentToken.equals(JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)) {
        /* .... */
      } else {
        ctxt.handleUnexpectedToken(classOf[X], p)
        ??? // is there a better way?
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT2: TLDR & never mind, maybe simply wrap that function in a function returning Nothing?

I usually do this by declaring an exception as result type. Let me show you in Java. Should translate easily.

```
RuntimeException functionThatAlwaysThrows() {
    throw new WhateverRuntimeException();
}
```

And then I simply use it by prefixing with throw:

```
throw functionThatAlwaysThrows();
```

Note that the 'throw' used here never actually 'happens', it's there only to tell the compiler what's happening. Since the exception is thrown inside the function, there is no change in outcome should one forget to add the 'throw'.

And often, the compiler's flow analysis will notify you if you forget it; not in completely imperative code of course, but your question seems to talk about a context where one would not be able to omit it.

There is a design decision to make on what type of exception to declare as the return type; it doesn't have to be related to the exception thrown, actually, but it's probably less confusing if it is. Works for checked and unchecked exceptions, of course, but I am guessing Scala doesn't have checked exceptions.

EDIT: I see now that you're not the implementer of the function called. So I guess the idea would be to simply wrap that function in a function as I've described. Or maybe it already declares an exception as return type?

Comment: Wrapping that function in a function returning `Nothing` is a nice idea, but it is not easy to do, as function returning `Nothing` must not return anything, not even `Unit`. You are facing the same problem then - the last expression in the wrapping function must be of type `Nothing`.

Comment: The Jackson `handleUnexpectedToken` is declared to return `Object`. It is possible to adapt your idea to following, though: `throw new Exception(ctxt.handleUnexpectedToken(classOf[CommodityType], p).toString)
`. Not very nice, but I still like it better than the `???` I was using before. I could also use `throw null` after the `handleUnexpectedToken` (with a comment explaining it is actually never reached).

Comment: @Suma Yes, true, it's a bit heavy for such a simple thing, but OTOH you do get more 'intentional', self-documenting code I feel. Regarding wrapping, I was thinking simply call the original function, then throw whatever as the last statement/expression (I don't really now Scala). Might want to throw something indicating an error since you didn't expect the original function to return. Or perhaps there is something in the standard library that returns Nothing that one could use instead?

Comment: you can `.asInstanceOf[Nothing]`

Comment: @SethTisue I think this could be an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: sure, somebody/anybody feel free to make it an answer